# Visual Studio 2015 builds my project without problems, MSBuild.exe cannot

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, jenkins, msbuild

I am developing simple Asp.net MVC 5 app which is working ok and visual studio 2015 can build it without any issues, but when i use MSBuild.exe command line tool it shows alot of errors which relates to typescript files compilation (primarily from node_modules folder).

I am trying to use Jenkins CI tool to automate my deployment routine, in order to do so i have to build my app using MSBuild.exe.

My project has tsconfing.json file in the root folder which contains following lines to exclude node_modules folder (it is inside @AngularComponents folder):

```
 "exclude": [ "Scripts/**", "WrittenScripts/@AngularComponents/**" ]
```

But somehow MSBuild.exe command line tool just ignores it during build.

Does anyone have any ideas how to configure it to take into account my tsconfig? or tell MsBuild to not to build my node_modules folder?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of msbuild are you using? What is the path to msbuild.exe?

Comment: I tried different versions of msbuild.exe (different paths). Some of them were: 1) C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe; 2) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe; 3)C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe. But the result is always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
First of all i have to use this MsBuild:

1) **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe;**

Secondly, for some reason msbuild messed up my tools version 4.0 so I need to pass additional parameter to msbuild:

2) **/tv:14.0**

Thirdly, my typescript files have some **/// references** to **node_modules\@types** folder and for some reason it shows me any errors but not related to the reference one.

3) so i have to run **npm install** to recover **@types** packages.

After these steps msBuild builds successfully without any errors.

Thanks for all!